# Ruby on Rails - Compare Active Record Result to Array Containing New Instansiated Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

In my Rails app I am doing two things - comparing an Active Record result to an array built from a JSON response from external API.

First step is checking which results are in the database and not in the API and I do this as follows:

```
def self.orphaned_in_db
  db_numbers = self.find(:all).map{|x| x.number}
  listed_numbers = self.all_telco.map{|x| x.number} # gets JSON from API
  orphaned_numbers = db_numbers - listed_numbers
  orphaned_results = self.find_all_by_number(orphaned_numbers)
  return orphaned_results
end
```

This is the new version as the old version was taking far too long after the result sets of each increased dramatically in the last few weeks.

```
 # def self.orphaned_in_db
  # old version
  # db_numbers = self.find(:all)
  # listed_numbers = self.all_telco
  # orphaned_numbers = []
  # db_numbers.each do |db|
    # scan = listed_numbers.select{ |l| l.number == db.number}
    # orphaned_numbers.push(db) if scan.empty?
  # end
  # return orphaned_numbers
# end
```

I am now finding it tricky to do the opposite of this - find numbers in the API array that are not in my database table.

```
def self.orphaned_in_telco
  db_numbers = self.find(:all).map{|x| x.number}
  all_numbers = self.all_telco
  listed_numbers = all_numbers.map{|x| x.number}
  orphaned_numbers = listed_numbers - db_numbers
  orphaned_results = # how to filter all_numbers by orphaned_numbers?
  return oprhaned_results
end
```

Again, the old way that now fails to work because it's so slow:

```
# def self.orphaned_in_telco
  # original, inefficient way
  # db_numbers = self.find(:all)
  # listed_numbers = self.all_telco
  # orphaned_numbers = []
  # listed_numbers.each do |l|
    # scan = db_numbers.select{ |db| l.number == db.number}
    # orphaned_numbers.push(l) if scan.empty?
  # end
  # return orphaned_numbers
# end
```

I am finding this difficult because it's the same view and partial that was used before to display these orphaned numbers (both iterations) but it's legacy code so I've never seen it working in action but I'm just confused how it worked before with Active Record results and a normal array.

The view is just:

```
<%= render :partial => 'list_item', :collection => @telco_numbers ) %>
```

Where `@telco_numbers` is set to the return value of the above methods. (`@telco_numbers = TelcoNumber.orphaned_in_telco params[:page]`)

The partial is as follows:

```
<tr>
<td>

<%= (link_to list_item.organisation.name.truncate(30), :controller => 'organisation', :action => 'update', :id => list_item.organisation.id) if list_item.organisation %>
</td>
<td class="centre"> <%= link_to ((list_item.countrycode == "44" ? Telco.format_uk_number(list_item.number) : "+#{list_item.countrycode} #{list_item.number}")), {:action => 'update', :id => list_item.id} %></td>
<td class="centre"><%= list_item.route_technology %></td>
<td><%= list_item.route_destination if list_item.route_destination %></td>
<td class="centre">
    <% if !list_item.new_record? %>
    [ <%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'update', :id => list_item.id} %> ]
    <% else %>
    [ <%= link_to 'Add New', {:action => 'update', :telco_number => list_item.attributes } %> ]

    <% end %>
</td>
```

So as I understand it, for the the version I am trying to fix, instead of having an `Edit` action, it would have an `Add New` link since it's not in my database table yet so I am just trying to figure out how to refactor the inefficient version so that it will still work with the shared view.

If it helps, the format of the JSON API response is :

```
[{"country_code":"44","number":"1133508889","block":null,"type":"Legacy","SMS":"0"},
```

So only `country_code` and `number` correspond to columns in my database table, the rest isn't necessary, hence the `if` statements in the partial to only show certain parameters if they are available.

**UPDATE**

After changing the method to the following as suggested by Chris Vo, it finally works after taking ages to complete but it's still not quite right.

```
def self.orphaned_in_telco
  # original, inefficient way
  db_numbers = self.find(:all)
  listed_numbers = self.all_telco
  orphaned_numbers = listed_numbers - db_numbers
  orphaned_results = []
  orphaned_numbers.each do |n|
    item = self.new()
    item.id = n
    orphaned_results.push(item)
  end

  return orphaned_results

end
```

The number column in my view html table just contains the `+` character and the `Add New` link doesn't have any value for the `countrycode` and `number` url parameters (link url is correct and all parameters are in the query string but they are all empty).

Some of the methods in my model:

```
def self.max_search_results
  return @@max_search_results
end

#for pagination
def self.per_page
  20
end

def self.some_telco(per_page, page = 1)
  page = 1 if page.nil?
  api_call = TelcoApiv3.new("post", "/numbers/#{TelcoApiv3.account_id}/allocated/all")
  listed_numbers = TelcoApiv3.poll(api_call.response["link"])
  return listed_numbers.collect do |ln| 
    ln.store("countrycode", ln["country_code"])
    TelcoNumber.new ln
  end
end

def self.all_telco(page = 1)
  listed_numbers = some_telco(@@max_nlist_results, page)
  if listed_numbers.length == @@max_nlist_results
    return listed_numbers.concat(all_telco(page + 1))
  else
    return listed_numbers
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, is the numbers column indexed?

Comment: @TheIrishGuy, just checked, `number` and 5 other columns are indexed (including primary key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if, for the `orphaned_in_telco` method, after you find the `orphaned_numbers` you create an instance of your model for every number in that set and then push it in a table to return them... or at least something in that direction. e.g.

```
orphaned_results = []
orphaned_numbers.each do |n|
 item = self.new()
 item.id = n
 orphaned_results.push(item)
end

return orphaned_results
```

And then from the partial when you call `Add new` you would only need to call `save` on that instance.

This way you won't have the problem of Active Record and array for the partial, since you will be returning an array of Active record instances.

Also, my suggestion for speeding up things, would be to use a Hash to store the keys/numbers.

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

In order to have the countrycode and speed up things a little, I will continue with my Hash suggestion:

So, let's start from your initial implementation:

```
#this returns everything from the API
all_numbers = self.all_telco

#this returns a Hash in the form {:number => :country_code}
listed_numbers = Hash[all_numbers.map{|x| [x.number,x.country_code]}] 
#so now you can do
orphaned_numbers = listed_numbers.keys - db_numbers
orphaned_results = []
orphaned_numbers.each do |n|
  item = self.new()
  item.number = n
  item.countrycode = listed_numbers[n]
  orphaned_results.push(item)
end

return orphaned_results
```

This should give it a boost and also send the country_code to the front side.

Comment: thanks, running now, still very slow (DB is ~ 60,000 and API is ~ 150,000)

Comment: after rendering (still takes ages to complete), the number column in my view html table just contains the `+` character and the `Add New` link doesn't have any value for the `countrycode` and `number` url parameters, any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer, basically you didn't see the number and countrycode from my first answer because I used `id` instead of `number` and I didn't add `countrycode` in the returned model instance. Hope it helps more now. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try just now.

Comment: It seems to run but when it's finished it throughs a 500 error - even on development. The log just says: `Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  closed MySQL connection` but it seems like the partial is being rendered thousands and thousands of times aswell `rendered telco_number/_list_item (1.4ms)` x a bajillion. `Completed in 453933ms (View: 381934, DB: 393) | 200 OK `[http://localhost/telco_number/list/TelcoOrphaned?page=1] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Nov 20 12:59:50 +0000 2013`

Comment: Could it be that you have a lot of things in the API that are not in the DB? If yes, then you might need to look at paging...
Take a look at the [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem.

Comment: yeah, that is the case, I currently use a plugin called paginate (still on rails 2.3.14)

Comment: Although, I see you always carry around a variable `page`, you don't actually use it somewhere, at least to the code you posted. When you say a plugin called paginate you mean the gem [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)? If that's the case, I don't see any calls related to that either. So maybe you have it installed, but you are not actually using it?

Comment: It might have been converted to a gem for rails 3 but for rails 2 it's a plugin. I think I have it now, I tried importing the API results into a new database table and it's much quicker now and I knew how to use `paginate` with the active record results whereas before I wasn't sure how it would work with the outcome of the difference (as you pointed out)

Comment: Cool! So, what are you still looking for? With all the updates, I kind of lost the target.

Comment: me too! was probably too large a question to expect someone alien to my personal codebase to answer. The code you gave helped but I couldn't get it to work exactly like how I wanted. I will mark it as accepted just now.

Answer (score 2):

But first you're going to want to cut down on your db calls.

```
 self.find(:all) #stupid slow
```

I'll point you in a right direction with

```
self.where('number NOT IN (?)', array_of_phone_numbers)
```

This will find all records that are not in the json data.

Comment: thanks but finding numbers in the database that aren't in the api is working (but I will take this advice and work on improving it), it's the opposite I am struggling with - getting numbers that are in the API but aren't in my database.